# merge multiple columns with condition

Tags: r, merge

I have a data frame like this:

```
   Q17a_17 Q17a_18 Q17a_19 Q17a_20 Q17a_21 Q17a_22 Q17a_23  
 1 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
 2  0       0       0       0       0       0       1
 3  0       0       0       0       0       1       1    
 4  0       0       0       0       0       0       1
 5  1       0       0       0       1       1       0
 6  0       0       0       0       0       1       1
 7  1       1       0       0       1       0       1
```

And I would like to merge Q17a_17, Q17a_19 and Q17a_23 in a new column with a new name. The "old" columns Q17a_17, Q17a_19 and Q17a_23 should be deleted. 
In the new column should be just one value with the following conditions:  "NA" if there was "NA" before, "1" if there was somewhere "1" as value before (like in row 3 or 4 or 7) and "0" if there were only zeros before.
Maybe this is really simple, but I struggle already for hours...

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use here is to first compute a vector which is `NA` when an `NA` value occurs in at least one of the three columns, and zero otherwise.  Also, we compute a vector containing the numerical result you want.  What you want can be obtained by logically ORing together the three columns.  Then, adding these two computed vectors together produces the desired result.

```
na.vector <- df$Q17a_17 * df$Q17a_19 * df$Q17a_23
na.vector[!is.na(na.vector)] <- 0
num.vector <- as.numeric(df$Q17a_17 | df$Q17a_19 | df$Q17a_23)
df$new_column <- na.vector + num.vector
df <- df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("Q17a_17", "Q17a_19", "Q17a_23"))]
```